# Why does the WordPress official website show a fake release date?

Tags: wordpress-version

I am just wondering why the WordPress official website is showing an incorrect release date for the [**4.4.14 version**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.4.14).

> On 16 January, 2018, WordPress 4.4.14 was released to the public.

The current WordPress version is [**4.9.2**](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions), also this version's release date is the same.

> On 16 January, 2018, WordPress 4.9.2 was released to the public.

Comment: The correct answer has already been given, but I'm curious _why_ you think the date is wrong, or "fake" as you say.

Comment: this is barely on topic. The right place to ask this kind of question is the wordpress slack channels.

Answer (score 6):

It's not incorrect, let alone 'fake'. Security updates are often released as minor versions of previous releases.

See the release notes on the page you linked to:

> From the WordPress 4.9.2 release post: WordPress versions 4.9 **and
>   earlier** are affected by an XSS vulnerability in the Flash fallback
>   files in MediaElement 4.x, a library that is included with WordPress
>   4.9.

That issue also affected 4.4. Since WordPress automatically updates to minor versions, this version of 4.4 was released at the same time to ensure sites received the fix even if they were holding off updating to the next major versions.

Comment: Right, since you rejected my edit: Versions are written down as `major.minor.patch`. Security updates increase the patch value; not the minor value. Security updates are indeed backported to older versions, also as patch version.

The question, nor the answer, has nothing to do with minor versions. This answer is correct, but uses the wrong terminology.

Comment: WordPress doesn't use that terminology: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/about/release-cycle/version-numbering/ In WordPress terminology it's a minor version.

Comment: Correct. WordPress does not follow [semantic versioning[(https://semver.org/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge misconception that wordpress has only one version being available at a time.

The reality is that while new features are being added only to the "in development" release, old releases (as old as 3.8 IIRC) are receiving security updates and a new version of them is created with those updates. There is nothing to prevent people from treating all those versions as what other software call "LTS release*".

As security updates are best done in a synchronized way across all the affected code, it would actually be very surprising to have the latest N release to not have the same release date.

*I am using the term LTS here in a minimal way. There is much more to the concept of LTS than being able to get security updates.